# How do i fix this error in WCF services?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-applications, service

I am currently attempting to use WCF services to input data into a database,

I have been following the steps of this tutorial: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/inserting-data-into-database-using-wcf-service/

and I have reached the end of it successfully:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWplC.png)
however, when I press the button, data does not get put into the database; instead this message pops up:

`Server Error in '/' Application`.

The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.
```

Source Error:

```
Line 146:        
Line 147:        public string InsertUserDetails(WebAppTest2.ServiceReference1.UserDetails userInfo) {
Line 148:            return base.Channel.InsertUserDetails(userInfo);
Line 149:        }
Line 150:
```

Source File: `c:\users\mauro-buhagiarjl(848\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebAppTest2\WebAppTest2\Service References\ServiceReference1\Reference.cs`    Line: 148

Stack Trace:

```
[FaultException: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +153
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +336
   WebAppTest2.ServiceReference1.IService1.InsertUserDetails(UserDetails userInfo) +0
   WebAppTest2.ServiceReference1.Service1Client.InsertUserDetails(UserDetails userInfo) in c:\users\mauro-buhagiarjl(848\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebAppTest2\WebAppTest2\Service References\ServiceReference1\Reference.cs:148
   WebAppTest2.WebFormTest.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\users\mauro-buhagiarjl(848\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebAppTest2\WebAppTest2\WebFormTest.aspx.cs:27
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9712582
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +204
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1639


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1637.0
```

Any Ideas to where this message originates from?

Comment: Debug the method in the service that is called when you run it. What you have shown is not helpful as it shows nothing about the original exception that caused this.

Comment: Hi, I have debugged my code and the error originates from nullexceptionreference handler on the following sqlconnection object: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BookStoreMembers"].ToString()); ------- Do you know how I can fix this and handle the exception?

Comment: I would guess you don't have a connection string by that name in the config file. You cannot call `ToString()` (or anything else) on a null reference.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. However now I get an unhandled timeoutexception... anyideas?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.7036820. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

Comment: Again, no way to know if you are not propagating errors to the client. A guess would be that your connection string is incorrect and the request times out while the `SqlConnection` is trying to find the server.